# Unrecognized configuration section log4net

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

I have this code in web.config:

```xml
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
  </root>
  <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="D:\logFileFaculty.txt" />
    <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

And I have downloaded `log4net.dll` and placed it in `Bin` Folder.

In one of My `aspx.cs` pages I have added this code:

```
using log4net;
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]


private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

But it's giving error as `Unrecognized configuration section log4net`.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You need to declare the `log4net` section:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>
```

Take a closer look at the [`documentation`](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) which explains the necessary things to do.

Comment: Being an utter noob at C#, I followed the instructions (almost) by opening the app.config file, finding another <section> element, and pasting the log4net one right above. it.  I didn't realize at first that I had pasted it *inside* a <sectionGroup> tag.  That didn't work.   So I finally realized my mistake and pasted it directly inside the <configSections> element.  20 minutes of my life chalked up to haste and carelessness.

Answer (score 1):

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
    </configSections>
</configuration>
```

add to your app.config file

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why not post the whole example.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  ...
  <log4net>
    ...
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```