# Configuration section 'log4net' is missing a section declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, log4net

I'm struggling adding log4net to my MVC5 project. I have done the following;

> Install-Package log4net

which has successfully installed (I assume) log4net

I have added the following to my web.config inside the cofiguration section;

```xml
<log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="Logs\ApiLog.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
           <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

and I have the following added to my configSections in the web.config;

```xml
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
```

I have added the following to my Global.asax.cs;

```cs
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

The solution compiles, However when I try to run my program I get the error;

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related
>   configuration data for the page is invalid.
>
> The configuration section 'log4net' cannot be read because it is
>   missing a section declaration

Does anyone have anyideas what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: Just refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419540/unrecognized-configuration-section-log4net

Comment: Is the `log4net` section placed after the `configSections` section?

Comment: @David  for some reason the package doesn't seem to have configured correct through Nuget. After running an update-package -reinstall this seemed to flush the error out. Thanks for you responses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unrecognized configuration section log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419540/unrecognized-configuration-section-log4net)

Answer (score 28):

You need to include this as well in web.config

```xml
<configSections>   
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>
```

it should look like below, Also make sure you have log4net.dll, log4net.xml in your Application bin folder

```xml
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>    
  </appSettings>
  <log4net xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/log4net.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="logfile.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value=".yyyyMMdd.lo\g" />
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
      <countDirection value="1" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level [%thread] [%aspnet-session{SessionId}] %logger - %message%newline%exception" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: Rolwin, I have updated my answer, as you can see this does already exist.

Answer (score 8):

You're probably missing to declare the config section. Try this in your web.config:

```xml
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" requirePermission="false" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  <configSections>
<configuration>
```

Comment: hi Kay I have edited above, it is there as posted see any issues?

Answer (score 5):

Note: You need to have section name **outside sectionGroup** in **configsections**

```xml
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
<sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
</sectionGroup>
```